# How to reference a 32-bit dll in a 64-bit vb.net windows application

Tags: c++, vb.net, exception, dll, dllimport

We are developing a windows form application in vb.net with over 400 projects in the solution and are built in 64-bit architecture. Now, we have an external dll of c++ type with 32-bit architecture which we are able to refer in our application, but throws an error like this

*"an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (exception from hresult: 0x8007000в)"*

Is there anyway that I can run the application and refer the dll without changing all 400 projects to 32-bit architecture?

Comment: What does the dll do?

Comment: 400 projects in a Winforms app??? Lord, my curiosity is piqued.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't load a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit process.**

You'll need to implement a 32-bit bit EXE process to host the DLL and invent an IPC mechanism to broker calls to it.  An out of process [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) EXE seems like the likely choice.